# Are sql queries with WITH statement and without equal?

Tags: sql

I have two queries:

```
WITH table1
     AS (SELECT id,
                first  AS table1_first,
                second AS table1_second
         FROM   some_table)
SELECT omt.*,
       t1.*
FROM   one_more_table omt
       INNER JOIN table1 t1
         ON omt.id = t1.id;
```

and

```
SELECT omt.*,
       t1.*
FROM   one_more_table omt
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                          first  AS table1_first,
                          second AS table1_second
                   FROM   some_table) AS t1
         ON omt.id = t1.id;
```

Tell me are this two sql queries equal?

Comment: The result would be same. but the first one uses CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a logical point of view, yes they are identical.

However some DBMS apply different optimization strategies for common table expression (first query) and derived tables (second query).

If you added a where condition in the "outer" query that restricts the rows inside the CTE it might not be pushed down into the CTE and thus might yield a different execution plan.

But this depends on the DBMS being used (the above is at least true for Postgres and I think Oracle. I don't know about e.g. DB2, SQL Server or other DBMS).